# Size on disk of a virtualized folder - How big can ProgramData actually measure?

Tags: windows-7, linux, file-management

*According to File Explorer in Windows 7 my system's ProgramData folder is 1,6 GB in size for 2541 files in 953 folders.*

*According to Thunar in Debian Linux my system's ProgramData folder is 120 GB in size in 284892 files.*

*According to Nautilus in Debian Linux my system's ProgramData folder is 2.8 GB in size in 284686 files.*

---

I'm not entirely sure of what I'm doing because ProgramData is a so called "virtualized folder" and while I would lean to listen to the native file manager I'm still not confident about what's going on.

I somehow suspect the Linux file managers are pulling in data which actually reside in other folders.

There is any other (more) reliable method to measure the size of this folder?

**While doing my backup (with clonezilla or wmware converter) how big can I expect this folder to be in size?**

Comment: what does `du` say in Debian?

Comment: these are the last two strings of du:

`2.0G /media/name/OS/ProgramData/Microsoft`
`2.6G /media/name/OS/ProgramData`

Comment: And you're sure that win7 displays 1.6G and not 2.6G?

Comment: Indeed I'm sure, even running with admin privileges Windows' File Explorer shows 1,6 GB and much less files count.

Comment: Do you have disk compression turned on on your NTFS perhaps?

Comment: The drive is not compressed, it's indexed.

Comment: I would think the file manager doesn't have access to the total amount of data for some reason, but I don't really know my way from here. (btw, I'm not considering Thunar estimates anymore because it measured a folder in 535GB on a 500GB hard drive, still there's a huge difference in files count between Nautilus and File Manager)

Comment: You should check the disk for any inconsistencies. sounds a lot like you have corrupt files / sectors on your disk.

Comment: In effect Clonezilla is warning me the partition is corrupted..  funny thing is that it seems chkdsk /f is not working in this case.